# Could someone please tell me how I could simplify this code?

Tags: javascript, function

In practice I have this code and it seems very tiring to do all those if there is a way to make it easier?
But that it works correctly? Because this code not only has * (multiplications) it also has 3 / (divisions).
If it only had multiplications it was easy to do it but it also has those divisons so it becomes more difficult to do so.
If anyone could help me thanks.

```
        function calculateLength() {
        
        
        
            var lengthinput = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lengthinput').value);


            var oper = document.getElementById('lengthselector1').value;
            var oper2 = document.getElementById('lengthselector2').value;


            if(oper === 'k' && oper2 === 'm')
            {
                document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput*1000 || 0;
            }

            
            if(oper === 'k' && oper2 === 'd')
            {
                document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput*10000 || 0;
            }

            if(oper === 'k' && oper2 === 'c')
            {
                document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput*100000 || 0;
            }
            
            if(oper === 'k' && oper2 === 'mi')
            {
                document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput*1000000 || 0;
            }

            if(oper === 'k' && oper2 === 'mic')
            {
                document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput*1.0000E+9 || 0;
            }               
            
            if(oper === 'k' && oper2 === 'de')
            {
                document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput*100 || 0;
            }

            if(oper === 'k' && oper2 === 'h')
            {
                document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput*10 || 0;
            }   

            if(oper === 'k' && oper2 === 'me')
            {
                document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput/1000 || 0;
            }
            
            if(oper === 'k' && oper2 === 'g')
            {
                document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput/1000000 || 0;
            }

            if(oper === 'k' && oper2 === 'z')
            {
                document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput/1.0000E+18 || 0;
            }               
            
            if(oper === 'k' && oper2 === 'i')
            {
                document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput*39370.0787 || 0;
            }

            if(oper === 'k' && oper2 === 'a')
            {
                document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput*1.0000E+13 || 0;
            }           
                            

        }
```

Comment: You could use a lookup table for the coefficient, e.g. `coefficient = { k: { mic: 1.0000E+9} }` and use it with `document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput*coefficient[oper][oper2] || 0;`

Comment: and how can I do this?

Comment: I didn't understand, could you explain it better?

Comment: You create a nested object containing all values and you use it to set `document.getElementById('lengthresult').value`.

Comment: in what sense? 
could you help me and modify a part of the code that I showed you, so I understand better

Comment: You can use a single `if` statement for `oper`, with a nested `switch()` for `oper2`: `if (oper === 'k') { switch(oper2) { case 'm': /*...*/ } }`

Comment: Also, you can write the divisons as multiplications instead. To make the code neater.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All your `if` conditions test for `oper==='k'`, so that can become just one `if` statement around all the rest. For `oper2` make a lookup table:

```
function calculateLength() {
    var lengthinput = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lengthinput').value);
    var oper = document.getElementById('lengthselector1').value;
    if (oper === 'k') {
        var oper2 = document.getElementById('lengthselector2').value;
        var coefficient = {
            'i': 39370.0787,
            'z': 1e-18,
            'g': 1e-6,
            'me': 1e-3,
            'h': 10,
            'de': 100,
            'm': 1e3,
            'd': 1e4,
            'c': 1e5,
            'mi': 1e6,
            'mic': 1e9,
            'a': 1e13
        }[oper2]; // <-- here we perform the lookup
        if (coefficient) {
            document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput*coefficient || 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `1.0000E+9` in your code is equal to `1e9`. The additional decimal zeroes do not change anything, nor does the `+` in the exponent part.

In some cases your code uses the standard notation, like 1000000, which can also be written in scientific notation: 1e6. I would try to use the same notation for all powers of 10, as then you can more clearly see how the different coefficients compare.

Also, a *division* by a power of 10 is the same as a *multiplication* by a power of ten where the exponent is negated: For example:

```
length/1e18 === length*1e-18
```

That means you can write all those coefficients as *multipliers*, and in scientific notation (except for the irregular 39370.0787 where you can opt to keep the standard notation).

Just to compare, you can write that lookup table ("mapping object") without scientific notation as follows:

```
    var coefficient = {
        'i': 39370.0787,
        'z': 0.000000000000000001,
        'g': 0.000001,
        'me': 0.001,
        'h': 10,
        'de': 100,
        'm': 1000,
        'd': 10000,
        'c': 100000,
        'mi': 1000000,
        'mic': 1000000000,
        'a': 10000000000000
    }[oper2]; // <-- here we perform the lookup
```

Comment: Could you tell me how did you get (1e3 / 1e4 / 1e5 / 1e6 .....)?

Comment: 1e3 is 10 to the power 3, so 1e3 is 1000. Maybe you prefer to write 1000 instead. But the higher the power, the more sense it makes to just write it in scientific notation. 1e4 is ten thousand, 1e5 is one hundred thousand. 1e6 is a million, ...etc.

Comment: So is it the same if I write 1000? And then I don't understand how this code where it was / (division) manages to do it like it does? in practice here 1e-3 why does a division?

Comment: Yes, it will be the same of you write 1000. `1000===1e3` is true. I added some explanations to my answer. `length*1e-3` is mathematically the same as `length/1e3`. Written in standard notation: `length*0.001` is the same as `length/1000`.

Comment: Yes, it was conditional for `oper` and now it also is for `oper2`. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a lookup table for the coefficient, e.g.

```
const coefficient = { k: { mic: 1.0000E+9, i: 39370.0787 } };
```

and use it with

```
document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput*coefficient[oper][oper2] || 0;
```

Example:

```
function calculateLength() {
    const coefficient = { k: { mic: 1.0000E+9, i: 39370.0787 } };
    const lengthinput = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lengthinput').value);


    const oper = document.getElementById('lengthselector1').value;
    const oper2 = document.getElementById('lengthselector2').value;

    if (oper in coefficient && oper2 in coefficient[oper]) {
        document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput*coefficient[oper][oper2] || 0;
    }    
}
```

That way you can easily extend it:

```
function calculateLength() {
    const coefficient = {
        k: { mic: 1.0000E+9, i: 39370.0787 },
        l: { abc: 123, def: 567 }
    };
    const lengthinput = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lengthinput').value);


    const oper = document.getElementById('lengthselector1').value;
    const oper2 = document.getElementById('lengthselector2').value;

    if (oper in coefficient && oper2 in coefficient[oper]) {
        document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput*coefficient[oper][oper2] || 0;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Including 'k' in the lookup table is nice. It makes the code very nice and simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
function calculateLength() {
  const data = [
    {
      oper1: "k",
      oper2: "m",
      time: 1000,
    },
    {
      oper1: "k",
      oper2: "d",
      time: 10000,
    },
  ];
  //---
  var lengthinput = parseFloat(document.getElementById("lengthinput").value);
  //---
  var oper = document.getElementById("lengthselector1").value;
  var oper2 = document.getElementById("lengthselector2").value;
  //---
  for (var count = 0; count < data.length; count++) {
    if (data[count].oper1 === oper && data[count].oper2 === oper2) {
      document.getElementById("lengthresult").value =
        lengthinput * data[count].time || 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another slight variation. I wrote this before I saw the other answers, so thought I might as well include it...

```
function calculateLength() {
    var lengthinput = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lengthinput').value);

    var oper = document.getElementById('lengthselector1').value;
    var oper2 = document.getElementById('lengthselector2').value;

    if (oper === 'k') {
        document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = (function () {
            switch (oper2) {
                case 'm':
                    return lengthinput * 1000 || 0;
                case 'd':
                    return lengthinput * 10000 || 0;
                case 'c':
                    return lengthinput * 100000 || 0;
                case 'mi':
                    return lengthinput * 1000000 || 0;
                case 'mic':
                    return lengthinput * 1.0000E+9 || 0;
                case 'de':
                    return lengthinput * 100 || 0;
                case 'h':
                    return lengthinput * 10 || 0;
                case 'me':
                    return lengthinput / 1000 || 0;
                case 'g':
                    return lengthinput / 1000000 || 0;
                case 'z':
                    return lengthinput / 1.0000E+18 || 0;
                case 'i':
                    return lengthinput * 39370.0787 || 0;
                case 'a':
                    return lengthinput * 1.0000E+13 || 0;
            }
        })();
    }
}
```